# Quick Inquiry About My Program

Tags: python, addition

I'm currently doing a programming concepts course for python and this is one of my assignments. I basically had to multiply through adding. I had it to the point where I have everything that needs to be done done but this right here is extra credit. I already submitted the assignment but now I'm here to just ask why this wasn't working.

The problem is that it wasn't working when the `yMult` variable was a float number. What I think was happening is that my counter (as the teacher wanted us to do it with a loop and a counter) is going up by 1 each time and if I have a floating point number as the `yMult` that it wouldn't have the `xMult` go up by like say .5. What would I do to fix this and/or what would it look like?

Here is the code I had made:

```
def add(xAdd, yAdd):    
     return xAdd + yAdd

def subtract(xSub, ySub):    
     return xSub + (-ySub)

def multiply(xMult, yMult):    
     total = 0.0    
     counter = 0.0    
     while counter > yMult:      
         if yMult <= 0.0:
             total = add(total, -xMult)
             counter = add(counter, -1.0)
     while counter < yMult:
         if yMult >= 0.0:
             total = add(total,xMult)
             counter = add(counter, 1.0)
     return total

def main():
    print multiply (5.5,9), multiply(9,5.5), multiply(2,4), multiply(2,-4), multiply(-4,2), multiply(-4,-2), multiply(4,1), multiply(1, 4), multiply(4, 0), multiply(0, 4), multiply(4, -1)

main()
```

The results were as follows: `49.5 54.0 8.0 -8.0 -8.0 8.0 4.0 4.0 0.0 0.0 -4.0`

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can fix this without some multiplication.
 If you want to go by 0.5 then you need to add half of another number which means multiplying it by 0.5.
 But if you are guaranteed to receive at least one integer then you could use it as counter:

```
def multiply(xMult, yMult):    
 total = 0.0    
 counter = 0.0    
 limit = yMult
 toAdd = xMult
 if isinstance(xMult,int):   
    limit = xMult 
    toAdd = yMult
 while counter <abs(limit):      
     if limit <= 0.0:
         total = add(total, -toAdd)
     else:
         total = add(total,toAdd)
     counter = add(counter, 1.0)
 return total
```

Comment: yeah, I know how I would do it with multiplication but the problem is that the professor explicitly said no multiplication anywhere in the problem XD